# using models in frontend? (vue vs ember)

Tags: vue.js, frontend, models

In Laravel I am used to define my models up front and to perform all actions on them.

However, it seems that most frontend frameworks just use whatever an API reponse provides and store the json data into simple arrays.

The only framework that I found using the model approach is Ember. I am missing this structure in the vue docs. I wonder why nobody seems to care about models. Are they just not that important in the frontend world?

Answer (score 0):

Using models in frontend frameworks is not that common due to JavaScript as a language. There are many benefits to strong typing, which is why there are nowadays multiple ways to add typing to the language.

Vue has support for [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/samples/index.html) which is a common way to define models in your JavaScript. TypeScript let's you define interfaces with certain types, so that you know that the data you have conforms to your model.

Answer (score 0):

That's where [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) comes in handy, Vue [supports it](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html), I don't know much about ember but I've found [this](https://pusher.com/sessions/meetup/ember-london/using-typescript-in-ember) and [Angular](https://angular.io/) has it out of the box. As far as I know backend developers learning front end technologies like Angular and TypeScript over other options because of the coding style.